# publisher policy in GAC

Tags: c#, assemblies, versioning, gac, publisher-policy

I want to redirect consumers of dll v1 to dll v2.
I will add a publisher policy in GAC for that.
Must the policy be in GAC?
Does this mean dll v2 itself must also reside in GAC?

Comment: Ok I admit I kind of know the answer to the first question but just want to verify. But I do not know the answer to the second - this *is* a real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the policy can be in GAC and the dll on disk.